# How to assign ng-model dynamically with a filter for a specific object in an array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is one right way to associate a input element to a specific field of a object in an array by its id?

I've implemented a solution with `ng-model` and the `find()` function from array prototype. It doesn't work fine, it just fill the input and in the beginning of page loading it returns the following error:

> Error: [ngModel:nonassign]

AngularJS file:

```
$scope.myData = [{
    "id": 51,
    "state": "A"
  },
  {
    "id": 52,
    "state": "B"
  },
  {
    "id": 53,
    "state": "C"
  },
  {
    "id": 54,
    "state": "D"
  }
];

$scope.bindObject = function(array, filterby, value, item) {
  let foundObject = array.find(obj => obj[filterby] == value);
  if (foundObject)
    return foundObject[item];
  else
    return $scope.default;
}
```

HTML file:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="bindObject(myData, 'id', id_value, 'state')"></input>
```

> PS. `id_value` is obtained from a web request;

Is there a most elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

ideas:
 
1. Return the object instead of the string. 
you basically don't need to know what the model is. just play with the object. 

 
2. You can also put a `"model"` property on your object.. 
see below

 
3. Use an if statement

not the best solution but this should get you going

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myData = [{
        "id": 51,
        "state": "A",
        model:"value_of_this_model"
      },
      {
        "id": 52,
        "state": "B"
      },
      {
        "id": 53,
        "state": "C"
      },
      {
        "id": 54,
        "state": "D"
      }
  ];
  $scope.bindObject = function(array, filterby, value, item) {
    let foundObject = array.find(obj => obj[filterby] == value);
    if (foundObject)
      return foundObject;
    else
      return $scope.default;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div ng-if="bindObject(myData, 'id', 51, 'state') != default">
  {{item = bindObject(myData, 'id', 51, 'state')}}
  <input type="text" ng-model="item.model" >
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw in another question that [we can't bind ng-model to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24177707/error-ngmodelnonassign-expression-is-non-assignable). And second issue is that I couldn't use the snippet `{{item = bindObject(myData, 'id', 51, 'state')}}` because it'd appear in my page. So I needed to convert my array into a json, using the `id` as the key:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myData = [
      {
        "id": 51,
        "state": "A",
      },
      {
        "id": 52,
        "state": "B"
      },
      {
        "id": 53,
        "state": "C"
      },
      {
        "id": 54,
        "state": "D"
      }
  ];
  
  let temp = {};
  for (let key in $scope.myData) {
            temp[$scope.myData[key].id] = $scope.myData[key];
                        
  } 
  $scope.myData = temp;
  console.log($scope.myData);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div>
  <input type="text" ng-model="myData[51].state" >
</div>
</body>
```